# Need some help to understand this statement

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces

Lemma: Meromorphic functions on the Riemann sphere are just the rational functions in $z$

Full proof of the Lemma can be find in p.2: http://math.uh.edu/~minru/6322-12/ruRSnote.pdf

And here is the part I don't understand.

> If $z_1, \dots , z_n \in C$ are the poles of f of degrees
>   $d_1,\dots,d_n$ then
>
> $$p := f (z-z_1)^{d_1}(z-z_2)^{d_2}......(z-z_n)^{d_n}$$
>
> has no poles on $\mathbb{C}$ and has at most a pole at $\infty$. This
>   means that $p$ is a polynomial

What does a pole at infinity means and is this really important to conclude that $p$ is a polynomial? And I think it is since there are other functions that doesn't have poles and isn't a polynomial. For example $\sin(z)$.

Comment: Right, $\sin$ has an essential singularity at $\infty$. If $h$ is a holomorphic function defined on a set that contains $\{ z \in \mathbb{C} : \lvert z \rvert > R\}$ for some $R \in \mathbb{R}$, then $\infty$ is an isolated singularity of $h$. The type of the singularity is the type of singularity that $g$, where $g(z) = h(1/z)$, has at $0$.

Comment: f(z) has a pole at infinity means that g(z)=f(1/z) has a pole at 0.